# Calling external JS function to verify email

Tags: javascript

In my HTML form I have

```
<label for="email">Email:</label> 

<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required /><br><br> 

<label for="confemail">Confirm Email:</label> 

<input type="email" name="confemail" id="confemail" required /><br><br>
```

In my external JS file I have the function

```
function confirmEmail() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value
        var confemail = document.getElementById("confemail").value
        if(email != confemail) {
            alert('Email Not Matching. Try again');
        }
    }
```

How do I implement this function? When I submit my form it doesn't actually use the function. If I add 2 different emails in the form, it allows me to carry on. I'm not talking about adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>`

Comment: You mean to say you have already included the script tag with the correct JS file? Also, please post the code that handles the submit form.

Comment: This code is run before anyone types or submits anything. For it to work you need to bind it to an input or submit event.

Comment: Yes I have the correct JS file. The form is not actually going anywhere. It's just a task I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following attribute to your form's submit button: `onclick="return confirmEmail()"`.

Like so:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return confirmEmail()" />
```

And this will be your function:

```
function confirmEmail() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value
    var confemail = document.getElementById("confemail").value
    if(email != confemail) {
        alert('Email Not Matching. Try again');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Explanation:

The [onclick event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick) you placed on the submit button will invoke your function. Returning `false` on your onclick event prevents the form from submitting. So if your emails-should-be-same condition fails the form will not submit.

There are also other ways of capturing the submit event. For example by using the [onsubmit event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onsubmit) on a `<form>` element.